# SQL count of different date occurencies from one table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In SQL I need to count occurrences of the date when a deal was passed to a salesperson, the meeting date, and the contract signing date, along with the sum of contracts.

All this data is in a single table with a unique ID as the primary key (PK).

The challenge is that I need to obtain the count of each of these dates by month without using any of the dates directly for grouping. This is because grouping by any of these dates directly would result in counting by that specific date.

For example, if someone had a meeting in January and we group by the meeting date, we wouldn't capture their contract in February, etc.

How should I approach this?"

I've tried unioning dates and also creating date array and cross joining but I had problem later with aggregation and I wonder ho it should be done properly.

Comment: posting the table along with the question would be great and the errors of what you tried as well. What is that needed in a table form. It will be easier to understand and solve for the members of the platform.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table sales
(
    uniqueid  int  not null identity(1,1),
    dealdate date,
    salespersonid int,
    meetingdate date,
    contractsigningdate date,
    contractAmt numeric(12,2)
);
insert into sales values ('2023-01-01',1,'2023-02-01','2023-03-01',10000)
insert into sales values('2023-01-02',  1,  '2023-01-07','2023-01-18',  10001)
insert into sales values('2023-01-03','1','2023-01-08','2023-01-19',10002)
insert into sales values('2023-01-04','1','2023-01-09','2023-01-20',10003)
insert into sales values('2023-01-05','1','2023-01-10','2023-01-21',10004)
insert into sales values('2023-01-06','1','2023-01-11','2023-01-22',10005)
insert into sales values('2023-01-01','2','2023-01-12','2023-01-23',10000)
insert into sales values('2023-01-02','2','2023-01-13','2023-01-24',10001)
insert into sales values('2023-01-03','2','2023-01-14','2023-01-25',10002)
insert into sales values('2023-01-04','2','2023-01-15','2023-01-26',10003)
insert into sales values('2023-01-05','2','2023-01-16','2023-01-27',10004)
insert into sales values('2023-01-06','2','2023-01-17','2023-01-28',10005)



select salespersonid,s.month,sum(dealcount)dealcount,sum(meetingcount)meetingcount,sum(contractcount)contractcount,sum(contractamt)contractamt from (
    select salespersonid, MONTH(dealdate)month,count(dealdate)dealcount,0 meetingcount,0 contractcount,0 contractamt from sales
    group by salespersonid,MONTH(dealdate)
    union all 
    select salespersonid,month(meetingdate)month,0,count(meetingdate),0,0 contractamt from sales
    group by salespersonid,month(meetingdate)
    union all 
    select salespersonid,month(contractsigningdate)month,0 ,0,count(contractsigningdate),sum(contractAmt) from sales
    group by salespersonid,month(contractsigningdate) 
) S
group by salespersonid,S.month
```